# centos 5.5 vsftpd user settings

Tags: ftp, centos5, vsftpd

I have a centos 5.5. with vsftpd installed.
i used some help from  http://centosforserver.blogspot.com/2010/02/virtual-hosting-with-vsftpd-and-mysql.html to set it up using mysql for user authentication

I also use ssl_enable=YES to have users the option to use secure logins 
the setting "force_local_logins_ssl=NO" is set to NO so both ftp and ftps are open.

Is there a way to manage it so that I can select which users have to use SSL and which users can still use FTP (for the transition time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vsFTPd really isn't designed to be that flexible, and it's not built to have the ability to apply arbitrary groups of options to arbitrary users. If you need the ability to do this using vsFTPd specifically, your best option is going to be running multiple instances on different ports and setting different options for each instance. This does sort of defeat the purpose of transitioning, though.

Comment: i changed my path and went with filezilla server, ...simple and works great.